# pickle a list as UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8, pickle

I want to import all files from one directory to my sql. But I have to make the same changes to each original .htb file first. The problem with the original file is that

1. I don't want to import the column headers and the 2nd line because its blank
2. I need to change \t\t\t\n to only \n so MySQL knows where fields and lines end
3. I need to remove -----\n because it only has 1 column which doesn't match my tabe (4 columns)
   Here's how the original .htb file looks like:

   Beschreibung\t  Kurzbeschreibung\t  Einheit\t   Wert\t\t\t\n

   \n

   Hub\t   Hub\t   mm\t    150.000000000000\t\t\t\n

   Bohrung\t   Bohru\t mm\t    135.000000000000\t\t\t\n

   -----\n

so far I have managed to create a list of all files. My next step would be to write that list to 1 single file which I can then edit. The problem I have is that I get a format issue when I save the list do a file. I want the final file to have utf8 format.
this is what I want my file to look like:

```
Hub Hub mm  150.000000000000            
Bohrung Bohru   mm  135.000000000000
```

but what I get at the moment is:

```
”ŒHub   Hub mm  150.000000000000            
”Œ%Bohrung  Bohru   mm  135.000000000000
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import pickle

folderpath = r"C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB" 
filepaths  = [os.path.join("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB/", name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []

for path in filepaths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        all_files.append(file)

with open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/DB Testdatensatz/HTB.htb", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(all_files, f)
```

Comment: It seems that `pickle` is simply not the right tool.

Comment: BTW: Without the input data, your issue is impossible to reproduce. However, you should hard-code example data in order to create a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickle` produces a binary format, which includes per field "header" bytes (describing type, length, and for some pickle protocols, framing data) that are going to look like garbage text if you view the output as text. You can't say "I want it to be `pickle`, but not have these bytes" because those bytes are part of the `pickle` serialization format. If you don't want those bytes, you need to choose a different serialization format (presumably using a custom serializer that matches this HTB format). This has nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding or lack thereof (your input is ASCII), the problem is that you are demanding a result that's literally impossible within the limits of your design.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, now i understand the error. Do you know a serialization format i can use to reach my goal? the reason i need the file to be utf8 is so i can import it to a mysql database

Comment: @Luis: It's unclear what's wrong with your original data in the first place. Why can't you just write out the data directly (opening the output file in mode `'w'`, `encoding='utf-8'`, and just calling `write`/`writelines` in some combination). Your desired output looks exactly like your likely input (which you haven't shown us, but it seems likely to be the same format you wanted in the first place).

Comment: My goal at the end is to import data into a mysql database. I have a couple thousand of .htb files wich have to be imported to mysql. But before i can import them i need to remove some characters from all those files.